# I am getting the bolded error messages for the following code

Tags: java

I am having a hard time finding the root cause for the error messages. I believe it had something to do with converting one data type to another. In my case, I am trying to convert String into int data type, I guess.

Here is the code and below are the error messages I am getting while running this code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class hw3_2
{
        private static void MyPermut(List<Integer> nums, int cur_i, List<List<Integer>> permuts){
        int n = nums.size();
        if(cur_i >= n){
            permuts.add(new ArrayList(nums));
            return;
        }
        for(int i=cur_i;i<n;i++){
            Collections.swap(nums, cur_i, i);
            MyPermut(nums,cur_i+1,permuts);
            Collections.swap(nums,cur_i,i);
        }
        return;
    }

    private static int check(List<Integer> path, int [][] g){
        int cost = 0;
        int u = 0, v = path.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<path.size();i++){
                v = path.get(i);
                if(g[u][v]==-1){
                        return -1;
                }
                cost+=g[u][v];
                u = path.get(i);
        }
        v = 0;
        if(g[u][v]==-1){
                        return -1;
                }
                cost+=g[u][v];
                return cost;
    }

    private static void solve(int [][] g, List<String> cities, HashMap<String,Integer> cityMap, int n){
        List<List<Integer>> permuts = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
                nums.add(i);
        }
        MyPermut(nums, 0, permuts);
        List<Integer> paths = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // paths with cost
        int ansPath = -1, ansCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<permuts.size();i++){
                paths.add(check(permuts.get(i), g));
                if(paths.get(i)!=-1 && ansCost>paths.get(i)){
                        ansCost = paths.get(i);
                        ansPath = i;
                }
        }
        System.out.print("Path:");
        if(ansPath==-1){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Cost:" + -1);
        }
        else{
                System.out.print(cities.get(0)+"->");
                for(int i=0;i<permuts.get(ansPath).size();i++){
                        System.out.print(cities.get(permuts.get(ansPath).get(i))+"->");
                }
                System.out.println(cities.get(0));
                System.out.println("Cost:" + ansCost);
        }
    }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                int t;
                // System.out.println("Enter no. of test cases :");
                t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                while(t--!=0){
                        // System.out.println("Enter the test case :");
                        int n, e;
                n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // no of cities
                int [][] g = new int[n][n]; //for graph with n cities adjacency matrix
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                                g[i][j] = -1;
                        }
                }
                List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
                HashMap<String,Integer> cityMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        String s = br.readLine();
                        cities.add(s);
                        cityMap.put(cities.get(i), i);
                }
                // for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                //      System.out.println(i + " " + cities.get(i));
                // }
                e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // no. of edges
                for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                        String u = st.nextToken();
                        String v = st.nextToken();
                        int w = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        g[cityMap.get(u)][cityMap.get(v)] = w;
                }
                // we have network of cities in graph 'g'
                solve(g, cities, cityMap, n);
                }
        }
}
```

**While running the code, I am getting these error messages**

````
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at hw3_2.main(hw3_2.java:81)
    Test case 0 Failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Fresno"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at hw3_2.main(hw3_2.java:81)
    Test case 1 Failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Fresno"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at hw3_2.main(hw3_2.java:81)
    Test case 2 Failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AA"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at hw3_2.main(hw3_2.java:81)
    Test case 3 Failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AA"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at hw3_2.main(hw3_2.java:81)
    Test case 4 Failed```
````

Comment: Okay. So did you *read* the error messages? What do you think `NumberFormatException` means? Where it says, for example, `For input string: "AA"`, were you *expecting* the code to try to convert `"AA"` into a number? If so, what do you think the result should be, and why? If not, then take a step back and ask why the code is trying to do that conversion.

Comment: "In my case, I am trying to convert String into int data type, I guess." You wrote this much code and you are *guessing* about the most basic aspects of what you're trying to do with it? You should only write code with a deliberate purpose in mind for every part.

Comment: You should try knowing the inputs. Seems like your variable `n` isn't getting an Integer rather is receiving a Letters.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and think more carefully about the logical process you want the code to follow. When you call `Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());`, you should have a reason to expect the `st.nextToken()` result to look like an integer (like, say, the documented *format* of the input), and a plan for what do do when that expectation is not met (because in the real world, input is broken).

Comment: Also, quit giving everything single-letter variable names. If you have to use a comment to explain what the name of a variable means, the name is wrong. You are making things harder for yourself because every time you have to use that variable, you have to spend extra effort remembering the secret code you used to name it. That takes much more effort than what you can possibly save in typing.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are converting contains other than the characters that are legal in an integer.

So, in something like this:

```
t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

then br.readline() returned something that wasn't just digits (and optional sign).  Or it returned null because you've hit the end of input.

The exception message tells you that what was actually read was "AA".  Which is clearly not an integer value.

So, the question is either:

- Why does the input contain AA when an integer is expected?

or equivalently:

- why are you trying to parse AA as an integer?